# XIB's are not being copied when building from command line

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcodebuild

Just a few hours ago I stumbled upon a strange problem: when building an OS X app in Debug mode (e.g. from within Xcode) everything works fine. But when I start the build from the command line using `xcodebuild -project xyz` no XIB files are being copied into the bundle.

The default for command line builds has been set to `Release`. Even when building the `Release` from within Xcode everything works fine.

The XIB files will not be copied when building from the command line, only.

Does anybody have a clue what might be the issue? I'm using Xcode 6.2.

**Update**

Just to mention it: all XIB files have been put into `Copy Bundle Resources` Build Phase.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for that.
Before compiling your project from the command line you should perform a `xcodebuild clean ...`.
After cleaning the app bundle contains all NIB files.

I've filed a bug because there was no such issue with former versions of Xcode.